# SerializeArray select multiple with jquery as json

Tags: jquery

I found this great function on SO to serialize forms (modified a bit).

```
function getFormData($form){
    var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
    for(var i in unindexed_array) {
            if(unindexed_array.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                $('[name="'+unindexed_array[i]['name']+'"][value="'+unindexed_array[i]['value']+'"]').each(function() {
                    $(this).attr('checked', true);
                })
            }
        }
    var indexed_array = {};
    $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
        if($.trim( n['value'] ).length)
        indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
    });
    return (!$.isEmptyObject(indexed_array) ? JSON.stringify(indexed_array, null, 2) : '');
 }
```

This works nice with inputs. Unfortunately not with multiple selects.
Find here a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t_book/00fyufde/

If I input and choose

- Animal: dog
- Plant: tree
- Cars: saab + volvo

It results in:

```
{ "first": "dog", "second": "tree", "cars[]": "saab" }
```

How do I have to change the function to respect the multiple select. In this case that "saab" and "volvo" shows up in json.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
$.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
        if($.trim( n['value'] ).length){
        if(indexed_array[n['name']] !== undefined){
             indexed_array[n['name']].push(n['value']);
        } else if(n['name'] !== undefined && n['name'].indexOf('[]') > -1){
          indexed_array[n['name']] = new Array(n['value']);
        } else {
          indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
        }
      }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/00fyufde/2/